# Zoom to extent of record in QGIS

Tags: qgis, atlas

I am using Data Driven Pages to create a set of maps showing locations I intend on visiting (forestry in a city). For navigation purposes my map shows the same location at 3 different scales, close, far and further.

How to get main data frame - the one the data driven pages are based on, to zoom to the extent of the record it is based on? Currently it is set to a fixed scale.

I have to go through my maps to adjust this data frame to fit the largest of the polygons and the rest are automatically set to this scale - but why can this not be automatically zoomed to the Polygone it is base on?

Comment: Please provide screenshots of your Atlas settings so far. Zoom to feature is usually the default setting.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve this using the following setting:

Under the Print Composer "Item Properties" panel:

- check X next to Controlled By Atlas
- check 'Margin around Feature'
- set the desired margin value around the feature

[image]

And I would think that the three maps in your composer / atlas pages could each have a different setting in order to achieve your "close, far and further" scales... each map in the page should have the 'lock layers' and 'lock styles for layers' options checked as well.